# Sharepoint site does not appear on IIS Manager, error in opening site in a sharepoint designer

Tags: administration, iis

I have created a site collection and then create two team sites on sharepoint server. Sites are working fine from central Admin but they are not appearing in IIS manager. Also when I try to edit a sharepoint site on sharepoint designer 2010 follwing error comes.

Unable to open website following causes:

1. the web server may not have sharepoint installed
2. The web server may be temporarily out of service
3. if you are connecting through a proxy server the proxy settings may be incorrect
4. An error may be occured in the web server

The IIS manager only showing the follwing sites Sharepoint 80 and sharepoint central admin

When I try to create a site on sharepoint designer following error comes:

The web site must be created on a server that is running microsoft sharpoint foundation server please chooose another location.

I have installed sharepoint server 2010, sharepoint foundation server 2010 and sharepoint designer on my pc.

Comment: My first question would be: Are your site collections and subsites under the SharePoint80 Web Application? You won't *see* site collections in IIS Mgr, just the Web Applications that contain them. As for SharePoint Designer accessing the sites, is this local on a VM? How are you connecting? Is there a DNS server handling name resolution?

Comment: 1) I don't know I will check it... (2) It's local PC. I have install sharepoint server 2010, designer 2010 and foundation server 2010 on my laptop. I m not using any Virtal Machine

Comment: Okay, so with everything running on your local PC.  Can you browse to the sites? In theory if you can browse to the sites you can open them in Designer..

Comment: You could not install SharePoint Server 2010 & SharePoint Foundation 2010 on the same computer.

Comment: yes, I can browse to the sharepoint sites from IIS as well as central admin.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would do is check your firewall settings if you have it enabled.

When opening a site inside SharePoint designer try entering the root URL, without subsites, lists, etc.

I would also look at editing the HOST file to ensure SPD is attempting to connect locally.

If you want a detailed analysis you need a traffic inspection tool(fiddler, netmon, etc).  I would look at Fiddler first since it is a bit easier to handle.  It will give you information on the communication happening between SPD and SharePoint, specifically what SPD is trying to connect to.  by looking at the HTTP packets you can see if SPD is making bad request or how the server is responding the request (if at all).

Comment: I solved this issue. The problem is of privelleges. When I login through built in Administrator account sp designer is working. There is a sp user which was present in a Administrator account and not in my other admin account so I add that user and it's working.