# SharePoint Designer 2010 Errors

Tags: sharepoint-designer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sharepoint site does not appear on IIS Manager, error in opening site in a sharepoint designer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16622/sharepoint-site-does-not-appear-on-iis-manager-error-in-opening-site-in-a-sharep)

I have installed SharePoint server 2010 and sp designer 2010 32 bit and ms office 2010 32 bit.

SharePoint server 2010 is working fine.

When I create a new blank web site on SharePoint Designer 2010
Error:
this web site must be created on a server that is running microsoft SharePoint foundation. Please choose another location.

When I open a site from sp designer following error comes.
Unable to open website following causes:

1. the web server may not have sharepoint installed
2. The web server may be temporarily out of service
3. if you are connecting through a proxy server the proxy settings may
   be incorrect
4. An error may be occured in the web server

When I click on customize my website on spdesigner 2010, this error comes
The server unexpectdly closed the connection

Comment: Are all three of these on the same server, or a different machines? In a domain or not?

Comment: On the same machine.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: I m using Windows 7